# How to generate controllers of a table that has multiple collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Here are my table structure and context:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AspnetIdentitySample.Models
{
    public class Employee : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MyTask> MyTasks { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    }
    public class MyTask
    {
        public int MyTaskId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime OldDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime NewDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsDone { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee User { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }



    public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Employee>
    {
        public MyDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // Change the admin of the table to be Users instead of AspNetUsers
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
                .ToTable("Employee");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .ToTable("Employee");
        }

        public DbSet<MyTask> MyTasks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    }


}
```

When I try to create a CRUD Controller using Entity Framework, It shows following error message. Any help would be appreciated. :)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*OP added more details and code. Original answer is obsolete and wrong*

/edit:

You are trying to tie 2 models to the same table:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Employee");
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .ToTable("Employee");
```

And additionally you try to add `public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }` which already should be in the datsabase as the identity table as defined by your context class definition.
I haven't tried to rename the aspnetusers table, but I'd try to remove the following lines:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Employee");

public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I don't Users table in my application though.

Comment: Please post your whole Dbcontext class in you question please.

Comment: let me try changing employee to users

Comment: sorry, but didn't worked. new message with "Employee" replaced with "User" came.. :(